# Have a Form opened multiple times with different Localizations in Visual Studio

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, localization

I'm developing a localizable product and Forms have the Localizable property set to True but it is difficult to me to work at the different versions of the Forms if I have to switch from on Language to another one. Is there a way to have the form opened twice (or more) with different localizations? (as they are really different forms using different .resx files I think that this should not be a problem)

Thanks in advance mates!

EDIT: Of course I'm talking about switching language at design-time to design the forms and apply changes done in one of the to all the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy your project to another directory and start another instance of Visual Studio.  Copy the .resx file back when you're done.

You could also consider using WinRes.exe, the stand-alone localizer.  It's available in the Windows SDK's bin directory.

Comment: Mmm, ok, this can work, its not a great solution because I cannot tab windows easily and because I have to start multiple VS but looks like the only one thing I can do. I think that MS should include something like this in VS2010.

Comment: Yes, what I would like is to set the docs horizontally tabbed to be able to compare them but I can do the same with all the VS stuff, so your anwser I think is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at this tool: [Zeta Resource Editor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ZetaResourceEditor.aspx)

> Zeta Resource Editor is a small utility application that enables you to edit string resources from multiple different resource files together inside one single data grid.

I have used this tool with great success in the past. The only thing you have to do is to include newly created .resx files in your solution.